# How does the decrement operator work in a while statement?

Tags: c, while-loop, decrement

I have the following code source in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i=0, x=3;
    while((x---1))
    {
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

How does this while statement work and why does it print 2 instead of 1?

Comment: I still like the `-->` operator better: `while(x-->0) {...}`

Comment: @nneonneo Suggests "x goes to zero" :) Mathematicians and IOCCC submission authors gotta love that.

Comment: I've used it myself in toy testing code because it's just so much easier than typing the equivalent for loop. But, maintainers will probably kill me if I try to submit it for real :)

Comment: I can't imagine why you would expect it to print 1. You ought to explain your thinking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `x---1` is really just `x-- - 1` which yields the value of `x - 1` before decrementing `x`.

Given that `x` has an initial value of 3, the loop runs 2 times (once with x = 3, once with x = 2, then next time x is 1, so `x - 1` is 0, and the loop doesn't run anymore).

So, `i` starts at 0 and it's incremented twice, so it ends up being 2.

Comment: Thank you, I now realized that x is decremented only by the x-- statement. I don't know why I thought that it was decremented twice: once by the x-1 and after by the x-- statement. But since it's not x=x-1, it doesn't change its value by this one. Took me a while to get to it though :)

Answer (score 5):

`(x---1)`  == `(x-- -1)`

<sub>because compiler try to choose bigger token first, So `---` interpreted as `--` & `-`</sub>

Expression `x-- - 1` means first `1` **subtracted** from current value of `x` due to `-` minus operation. Then `x` value **decremented**  by 1 due to postfix decrement operator `--`.

For example in before first iteration `x = 3`, so while condition is `2` (that is `3 - 1`) after that `x` decremented, and before next iteration `x = 2`.

`x = 3`, `i =0`;

- **1-iteration:**  `while(2)`,  and in loop `i` becomes  `1`

`x = 2`, `i = 1;`

- **2-iteration:**  `while(1)`,  and in loop `i` becomes  `2`

`x = 1`, `i = 2;`

- Now, `x - 1` = `0` that gives  `while(0)` and loop breaks and `i` not increment.

So after loop output `i`:  **`2`**

note one more point:  `i` does not increment as loop break because `i++` in while-block `{}`, but `x` decremented to `0`. After loop if you printf `x` then output will be `0`.

Answer (score 3):

So the the while probably makes more sense if you look at it with some more spaces:

```
while( ( x-- - 1) )
```

It is using a post decrement so x is modified after returning it's current value so it is really equivalent to this:

```
while( ( x - 1) )
```

and the loop will run until the expression is `false` or in the this case `0` which is equivalent to `false`. So the run goes like this:

```
x   x - 1   i
=============
3     2     1    x - 1 not 0 so increment i
2     1     2    x - 1 not 0 so increment i
1     0     2    Loop exits here and does not increment i again
```

At this point the loop exits and you hit the `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

`while((x---1))` is equivalent to `while((x-- -1 != 0))`, which in turn is the same as writing `while(x-- != 1)`. Since the value of `x--` is the value of `x` **before** the decrement, this is the same as

```
while(x != 1) {
    x--;
    ...
}
```

which runs twice if `x` starts at 3.